# Writing Built in Driver for Linux

Tags: linux-device-driver

What are the steps in developing a built in Linux driver?

I mean which files must I modify in order to make driver installed when the kernel boots up?

Thanks
Gest

Comment: THE FIRST STEP IS TURNING CAPS LOCK OFF!.

Comment: @RichieHindle Maybe we should leave him this way. I'd love to see his driver code in all caps.

Comment: How about searching and reading some nice docs on www.google.com ? ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. `cd /path/to/Kernel`
2. `make menuconfig`
3. Highlight **Device Drivers**, using arrow keys, and press Enter
4. Now highlight the driver that you want as built-in and press `y`

Note: Only the drivers prefixed with `< >`can be built as a module. Pressing `Y` includes, `N` excludes, `M` modularizes features.

**Also note that there are some drivers which have two states, i.e built-in or not-included, and these drivers cannot be modularized.**

Legend: [*] built-in  [ ] excluded   module  < > module capable

e.g If a user wants I2C drivers to be built in then

1. `cd /path/to/Kernel`
2. `make menuconfig`
3. Device Drivers----> (Highlight and Press Enter)
4. I2C support (Highlight and press 'Y')

Now M will be replaced by `*` i.e the I2C driver is now built-in.
Build the kernel now and have fun.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the right defconfig file for your target and config name for your driver or subsystem, you can directly add it into `/arch/xxxx(arm/sparc/..)/config/***_defconfig` as `CONFIG_I2C=y`.